# Why do I get the "DialogInterface.OnClickListner cannot be resolved to a type" error?

Tags: android

I am using a book to learn Android Development and I keep getting an error on DialogInterface.OnClickListerner(). The error eclipse gives me is "DialogInterface.OnClickListner cannot be resolved to a type". I check it over multiple times and my code is all case sensitive, and no misspelled words.

The name of my project is called 'Dialog' and the name of the class is 'DialogActivity'. My manifest minSdkVersion is set to 8 and my targetSdkVersion is set to 19 (just in case this info is needed). Here is the code function that's giving me the error:

```
@Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id){
        case 0:
            return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setTitle("This is a dialog with some simple text...")
            .setPositiveButton("OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListner() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton){
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "OK clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                )
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListner() {
                            public void OnClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Cancel clicked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                )
                .setMultiChoiceItems(items, itemsChecked, 
                        new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListner() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean isChecked) {
                            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), items[which] + (isChecked ? " checked!":" unchecked!"),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                ).create();

        }
        return null;
    }
```

If someone could point me in the right direction to solve this error, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are typos. It should be `OnClickListener` not `OnClickListner`. Similar issue in `OnMultiChoiceClickListner`.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add Button OnClickListner() so just remove

> DialogInterface.OnClickListerner()

and add simple Button OnClickListner()

> OnClickListener()

Answer (score 0):

Just delete your import files and re-import them with `DialogInterface.OnClickListerner()` instead of normal `OnClickListener()`